# How to connect a QSqlDatabase using TCP? (Qt's MySQL Driver)

Tags: qt

I am trying to connect to a local MySQL server, but cannot find out how to select if QSqlDatabase should connect through a socket or port. Qt is version 4.6.3. My simple test code is as follows:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
db.setHostName("localhost");
db.setPort(3306);
db.setDatabaseName("rem");
db.setUserName("test");
db.setPassword("test");

if (!db.open()) {
    qDebug() << db.lastError();
}
```

This gives me:

```
QSqlError(2002, "QMYSQL: Unable to connect",
    "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)")
```

As you can see it wants to connect using the default socket, which I don't want.

I found `db.setConnectOptions("UNIX_SOCKET=blabla")`, with which you can set the socket. Unfortunately I cannot figure out how to *unset* it.

Comment: This doesn't have to be community wiki, at least i think so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `db.setHostName("127.0.0.1");` instead.

Comment: Thank you. This works. Could you elaborate why this happens? I am thinking about how to let the user input the server address.

Comment: From the MySql Manual: On Unix, MySQL programs treat the host name localhost specially, in a way that is likely different from what you expect compared to other network-based programs. For connections to localhost, MySQL programs attempt to connect to the local server by using a Unix socket file. This occurs even if a --port or -P option is given to specify a port number. To ensure that the client makes a TCP/IP connection to the local server, use --host or -h to specify a host name value of 127.0.0.1, or the IP address or name of the local server. You can also specify the connection protocol